# Execute multiple url

Tags: php

I have a little problem. I need to execute an script that execute 5000 URL in php.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","psswd");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db_name', $con);

print "connected";

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT name, uid FROM obinndocusers");

// I need to execute that url for each user
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        header (Location http:xxxxxxxx?q=user/" . $row['uid'] . "/edit&destination=admin/user/user);
}
```

Any idea??

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

LIKE :

```
$ch = curl_init();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com?q=user/" . $row['uid'] . "/edit&destination=admin/user/user");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
}
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http:xxxxxxxx?q=user/" . $row['uid'] . "/edit&destination=admin/user/user");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: **header()** is a primitive to send http headers to browser. It must be called **before** any stdout output (like 'print' or 'echo').

Second thing: "Location: " header will tell your browser to redirect to that URL. You **can not** specify more that one URL.

If you need your script to do http queries, use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), and do not call your script from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be with CURL (see other answer by Haim Evgi), but if the server doesn't have the curl extension, then this will also work.

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","psswd");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db_name', $con);

print "connected";

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT name, uid FROM obinndocusers");

// I need to execute that url for each user
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        file_get_contents("http:xxxxxxxx?q=user/" . $row['uid'] . "/edit&destination=admin/user/user");
}
```